# How to find a character in a (cell) array of strings, Python

Tags: python, string, floating-point, cell-array

I am loading a .csv with Pandas (pd.read_csv). Normally this would yield floats, however a few of my datasets have a 'q' inside some of the > 100000 numbers (for instance a matrix of 33x60000) included in the .csv file. Like this: '-13q27.20148186934421000000' (the q's are NOT always in the same place). This causes Pandas to not see them as numbers but as strings. This makes a conversion to float impossible, hence my question: how can I easily find the 'q's and remove them?

I tried using a for loop and check for each individual string if it contains a 'q', this however takes ages:

```py
for i in range(tmp.values.shape[0]):
    for j in range(tmp.values.shape[1]):                           
       if 'q' in tmp.values[i,j]: 
          print('oh oh')
```

It is also possible that it is sometimes another letter then a 'q', so maybe it would be wise to look for letters in general, I have no idea how to do this in an efficient way.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick answers, but it seems I did not correctly describe the problem, so really the q's are within the numbers like this: '-13q27.20148186934421000000'

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex=True`:

Given `df`:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   1.1   2.2   3.3
1  2q.2  3.q4  q5.3
2   4.4   5.5   6.6

df = df.replace('q', '', regex=True).astype(float)
print(df.dtypes)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
col1    float64
col2    float64
col3    float64
dtype: object

   col1  col2  col3
0   1.1   2.2   3.3
1   2.2   3.4   5.3
2   4.4   5.5   6.6
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! This really helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can delete all characters (here q) from a specific column (here named result):

```
data['result'] = data['result'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('q').rstrip('q'))
```

afterwards you can convert your column to float.

```
data['result'] = data['result'].astype(float)
```

or alternativ:

```
df['result'] = df['result'].str.replace(r'\D', '').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.replace(['q'], 0.0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Perhaps explain what replace does and why this is what the OP requires?